# MySQL - Joins - Show Data When Doesn't Exist in Other Tables

Tags: mysql, join

I've got my join working like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fixtures f, 
     channel c, 
     fixture_channel_join fcj
WHERE f.matchday =  '1'
AND f.fixtures_id = fcj.fixture_id
AND fcj.channel_id = c.id
```

However, this only shows rows that has data in the channel and `fixture_channel_join`. Is it possible to display all data from fixtures, and if there are no joins just display null data in them columns?

Thanks

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did there is an implicit join, which is an `INNER JOIN`. It's hard to read and a bit confusing, I advise against it.

You're looking for `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`.
The `LEFT JOIN` gives you all values in the left side, filling up with `NULL` in the right part of the result:

```
SELECT *
FROM fixtures f,
LEFT JOIN fixture_channel fcj ON f.fixtures_id = fcj.fixture_id
LEFT JOIN channel c ON fcj.channel_id = c.id
WHERE f.matchday = '1'
```

This will give you all the values in the `fixtures` table (including those which don't match), followed by the matching values in the `fixture_channel` table (with `NULL` values where no matches exist), followed by the matching values in the `channe`l table (with `NULL` values where no matches exist).

Alternately, a `RIGHT JOIN` will give you all values from the right side, filling with `NULL` in the left:

```
SELECT *
FROM fixtures f,
RIGHT JOIN fixture_channel fcj ON f.fixtures_id = fcj.fixture_id
RIGHT JOIN channel c ON fcj.channel_id = c.id
WHERE f.matchday = '1'
```

This will give you all values in the `channel` table (including those which do not match), preceded by the values in the `fixture_channel` table (with `NULL` values for those who do not match any channels), preceded by the values in the `fixture` table (with `NULL` values for fixture_channel values that don't match fixtures). Went backwards on this to illustrate it's going right-to-left.

More about joins [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/), with illustrations :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it really helps!

Comment: You're welcome. Find some documentation like the one I suggested and get a good understanding on joins. They're very powerful if done right. Also, as a quick tip, never forget to add indexes on columns you join on, it really helps performance. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using `left join`

```
SELECT * 
FROM fixtures f
LEFT JOIN  fixture_channel_join fcj ON f.fixtures_id = fcj.fixture_id
LEFT JOIN  channel c ON fcj.channel_id = c.id
WHERE f.matchday =  '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using LEFT OUTER JOIN.

```
SELECT * 
FROM fixtures f
LEFT OUTER JOIN  fixture_channel_join fcj ON f.fixtures_id =fcj.fixture_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN  channel c ON fcj.channel_id = c.id
WHERE f.matchday =  '1'
```